# Authenticate to Graph API from Azure Functions with JavaScript

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I would like to create an azure function using NodeJS and authenticate to Graph APIs. Through my reading I know that I have to use client credentials flow. I am using this code as posted by:

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> 
    const APP_ID = [appId]';
    const APP_SECERET = '[secret]';
    const TOKEN_ENDPOINT ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
    
    const axios = require('axios');
    const qs = require('qs');

    const postData = {
        client_id: APP_ID,
        scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE,
        client_secret: APP_SECERET,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
      };
      
      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    axios
      .post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, qs.stringify(postData))
      .then(response => {
        context.res = {
           
            body: response.data //JSON.stringify(w, null, 4)
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

};
```

As mentioned in this post: [How to get users from azure active directory to azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109090/how-to-get-users-from-azure-active-directory-to-azure-function/60109903#60109903)

However this is not working as it's not even making a request to Azure. Is there something missing? Can't I use MSAL.JS to make server to server calls when am using Node or is it just for web based apps and won't work with azure functions?

Most of the examples am seeing are related to .Net and they're using bunch of nuget packages, etc.. Isn't what I need supported in JavaScript azure functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why did you say it's not even making a request to azure, I test it with almost same code with yours and it work fine. I provide details of my steps as below for your reference.

**1.** I create a type script function in VS code (do not forget declare `require` in the second line of my code), my function code show as:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
declare var require: any

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {

    const APP_ID = 'xxxxxx';
    const APP_SECERET = 'xxxxxx';
    const TOKEN_ENDPOINT ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

    const axios = require('axios');
    const qs = require('qs');

    const postData = {
        client_id: APP_ID,
        scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE,
        client_secret: APP_SECERET,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    };

    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    axios
      .post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, qs.stringify(postData))
      .then(response => {
        console.log('=====below is response====');
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log('=====above is response====');
        context.res = {
           
            body: response.data
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

};

export default httpTrigger;
```

**2.** I install `axios` and `qs` modules by the command:

```
npm install axios
npm install qs
```

**3.** To start the function, I ran the command:

```
npm install
npm start
```

**4.** After request the function, I get the result as:
[image]

Comment: When I run npm start, it gives me the url for my local function. I open a new browser tab and request this, but it just shows a blank page. I open fiddler and check if there's any request made to Azure but there's nothing, it's just one request made to my local function and returns nothing.

Comment: @BR1 When we start the function in VS code, it just host on local. It will give us a url for local function to request. In your function code(or my function code), we request for authentication in the function code when we request the local function url. Please note my funciton code(between `=====below is response====` and `=====above is response====`). We get the access token there and then we can use the access token to request graph api.

Comment: @BR1 If you want to request the function url to azure, you can deploy your function to azure but not run it in VS code in local.